# Is it possible to do JOINs in Sequelize without creating Foreign Keys?

Tags: sequelize.js

Based on what I have [read](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/eager-loading/):

> As briefly mentioned in the associations guide, eager Loading is the act of querying data of several models at once (one 'main' model and one or more associated models). *At the SQL level, this is a query with one or more joins*.

and [here](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/):

> The A.hasOne(B) association means that a One-To-One relationship exists between A and B, with the foreign key being defined in the target model (B).

> The A.belongsTo(B) association means that a One-To-One relationship exists between A and B, with the foreign key being defined in the source model (A).

> The A.hasMany(B) association means that a One-To-Many relationship exists between A and B, with the foreign key being defined in the target model (B).

> These three calls will cause Sequelize to automatically add foreign keys to the appropriate models (unless they are already present).

Elsewhere I have read foreign keys are bad for performance. e.g., [here](https://blog.koehntopp.info/2020/08/03/mysql-foreign-keys-and-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Is there any way to do JOINs in Sequelize without creating any FKs across the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to use defined models and their associations to create tables and foreign keys by calling `sync` it's your responsibility to have these foreign keys in DB or not (preferably using migrations). Sequelize only uses defined associations between models to build SQL queries with JOINs.

> These three calls will cause Sequelize to automatically add foreign keys to the appropriate models (unless they are already present).

Please pay attention that this paragraph tells about adding foreign keys to **models** and not to tables in DB.

Usually you use Sequelize **migrations** to add/modify tables/foreign keys (means you change the DB **structure**) and **models and associations** to create/red/update/delete records in DB (means you change **data** in DB).